# Endomorphisms as derivations

Tags: differential-geometry, multilinear-algebra

A derivation on tensors is a map $T \mapsto D T$ that preserves the type of the tensor $T$; is linear; commutes with contractions; and satisfies the product rule
$$
D\left(T_1 \otimes T_2\right)=\left(D T_1\right) \otimes T_2+T_1 \otimes D T_2
$$

Now for $v_1,\cdots,v_s\in V$, $\phi^1,\cdots,\phi_t\in V^*$ and $L\in End(V)$, we define
\begin{aligned}
&L\left(v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_s \otimes \phi_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes \phi_t\right)\\
&=L\left(v_1\right) \otimes \cdots \otimes v_s \otimes \phi_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes \phi_t\\
&+\cdots\\
&+v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes L\left(v_s\right) \otimes \phi_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes \phi_t\\
&-v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_s \otimes\left(\phi_1 \circ L\right) \otimes \cdots \otimes \phi_t\\
&-\cdots\\
&-v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_s \otimes \phi_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes\left(\phi_t \circ L\right) .
\end{aligned}

And it's easy to see that any $(1,1)$-tensor $L$ defines a derivation on tensors.

In *Riemannian Geometry* of Peter Petersen, he gives a proposition as follows:

If $L\in \mathcal{so}(V)$, i.e., $L$ is skew-adjoint, then $L$ commutes with type change of temsors.

I'm trying to show this conclusion through coordinates for $(0,1)-tensors$ as follows:

Suppose $T=a_{i}x^i$, $L=b_{i}^{j}x_j\otimes x^i$, where $b_i^j=-b_j^i$. We denote the type change operator by $C$, then
\begin{aligned}
C(L(T))&=C(-a_ib_k^ix^k)=-a_ib_m^ig^{mk}x_k.\\
L(C(T))&=L(a_ig^{ik}x_k)=a_ig^{ik}b_k^jx_j.
\end{aligned}
I think I can't show they are the same. Can anyone explain it and give a proof for general tensors?

Comment: Why would a derivation preserve the type of the tensor? The exterior derivative does not do this. For example, it turns a function into a $(0,1)$-tensor.

Comment: It's just a general definition in Petersen's Riemannian Geometry.